# SyntaxError in PySpark Code When Using List Comprehension for Aggregation Expressions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, syntax, aggregation

I'm encountering a syntax error when trying to perform aggregations on a DataFrame in PySpark. The goal is to group the data by certain columns and calculate various statistics, including mean, standard deviation, median, and quantiles for a list of numeric columns. However, I'm receiving a syntax error related to my use of list comprehension for defining the aggregation expressions.

Here's the section of code that's causing the issue:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date, datediff, when, mean, stddev, expr
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

# Code to initialize SparkSession and load data into DataFrame `df1`

# Convert numeric columns to double type for aggregation
numeric_columns = ['lead_time_1', 'lead_time_2', 'lead_time_3', 'def_to_rls2prod', 'inprog_to_rls2prod']
for column in numeric_columns:
    df1 = df1.withColumn(column, df1[column].cast(DoubleType()))

# Group by 'parnt_proj_nm' and 'itrat_nm' and calculate aggregations
aggregation_exprs = [mean(column).alias(f'mean_{column}'),
                     stddev(column).alias(f'std_dev_{column}'),
                     expr(f"percentile_approx({column}, 0.5)").alias(f'median_{column}'),
                     expr(f"percentile_approx({column}, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99))").alias(f'quantiles_{column}')
                     for column in numeric_columns]

aggregated_df1 = df1.groupBy('parnt_proj_nm', 'itrat_nm').agg(*aggregation_exprs)
```

The error message I receive is:

```
File "/tmp/ipykernel_1703805/107545517.py", line 105
    for column in numeric_columns]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This error points to the list comprehension used for generating the aggregation_exprs. I'm attempting to dynamically create a list of aggregation expressions to pass to the agg method of the DataFrame. I suspect the issue might be with how I'm using the expr function inside the list comprehension, but I'm not sure what the correct syntax should be.

Can someone help me understand what's wrong with this syntax and how to correct it? Any insights or suggestions on how to dynamically create aggregation expressions for a groupBy operation in PySpark would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to put parentheses around the comprehension target, i.e. `[do_a(item), do_b(item) for item in iterable]` is invalid syntax because `[do_a(item),` is parsed as if the first item of a list, so it must be grouped using parentheses up to the `for` to disambiguate that to one of list comprehension, i.e. `[(do_a(item), do_b(item)) for item in iterable]` will fix it.